# rails 4.2 : nil is inserted when trying to storing array data with PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql

I have a problem with storing array data into one field with PostgreSQL.

here is my environment

```
Rails version             4.2.0
Ruby version              2.2.0-p0 (x86_64-darwin14)
RubyGems version          2.4.5
Rack version              1.5
```

and my migration is

```
class CreateStartups < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :startups do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false
      t.string :email
      t.boolean :is_email_verified, null: false, default: false
      t.decimal :location_lat, precision: 10, scale: 6
      t.decimal :location_lng, precision: 10, scale: 6
      t.text :completeness, array: true, default: []
      t.datetime :deleted_at

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

and model is

```
class Startup < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :completeness, Array
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :slug, presence: true, allow_blank: false, length: { maximum: 200 }
  validates_uniqueness_of :slug
  translates :name, :name_ruby, :company_name, :concept, :about_title, :about_detail, :address
end
```

and what I tried to do was in rails console

```
    [6] pry(main)> Startup.create!(name: 'test', slug: 'test3', completeness: [100, ["test", "test2"]])
   (0.1ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  Startup Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "startups" WHERE "startups"."slug" = 'test3' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "startups" ("completeness", "slug", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["completeness", nil], ["slug", "test3"], ["created_at", "2015-02-19 10:17:23.355815"], ["updated_at", "2015-02-19 10:17:23.355815"]]
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "startup_translations" ("locale", "startup_id", "name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["locale", "ja"], ["startup_id", 4], ["name", "test"], ["created_at", "2015-02-19 10:17:23.364581"], ["updated_at", "2015-02-19 10:17:23.364581"]]
   (0.1ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
=> #<Startup:0x007fd840cc1648
 id: 4,
 author_id: nil,
 slug: "test3",
 email: nil,
 location_lat: nil,
 location_lng: nil,
 completeness: [],
 deleted_at: nil,
 created_at: Thu, 19 Feb 2015 10:17:23 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Thu, 19 Feb 2015 10:17:23 UTC +00:00>
```

And what i see is `completeness: []` is inserted because generated SQL was

```
INSERT INTO "startups" ("completeness", "slug", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["completeness", nil], ["slug", "test3"], ["created_at", "2015-02-19 10:17:23.355815"], ["updated_at", "2015-02-19 10:17:23.355815"]]
```

and completeness is nil even though I passed `[100, ["test", "test2"]`

could anyone help me out on this??

best,

Comment: Can you complete the array `[100, ["test", "test2"]]` and try..

Comment: What is the type of column `completeness` in your `schema.rb`? I see you used the `text` type in your migration, perhaps this should be changed to type `hstore`.

Comment: @zwippie _text_.. The OP mentioned.

Comment: @zwippie Yes, it is. I'm also currently working on similar kind of issue.. Need to dig into it more.

Comment: You can change the field type to a text column only, not an array. And serialize your array and save it to the column.

Comment: @zwippie  ``` t.text     "completeness",                                              default: [],                 array: true ``` this is the line in schema.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Yoshi, you are trying to store malformed array. 
Acceptable variants:

```
[[100], ["test", "test2"]]
[100, "test", "test2"]
```

Not acceptable variants:

```
[100, ["test", "test2"]]
[100, "test", ["test2"]]
```

Another words - array can only be or single-dimensional, or multidimensional.
See more at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html

Comment: thank you for your answer. however, i still have the same problem with single-dimension array insertion. @intale

Comment: @Yoshi, can you provide a version of your pg gem and a version your postgreSQL?

Comment: Hmm... Wait. Remove this line: `serialize :completeness, Array` and it should work right after. Or, otherwise, remove `:array => true, :default => []` from the column's options in the migration(and run migration again).

Comment: @intale Yes, your last suggestion worked right after. thx a lot ^^